# Installing gitLab missing modernizer?

Tags: linux, shell, debian, gitlab

I try to install gitlab on debian with this turotial: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

I'm at step "Install Gems" and try to run:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

i get this echo:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not find modernizr-2.6.2 in any of the sources
```

I don't find a solution for this error I run it as root as well.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I ran into this same problem a few minutes ago. Looks like the classy folks behind Modernizr's Rubygem yanked the most recent versions. You can download the latest gem (Modernizr-2.5.2 as required in the docs there) running the following command inside your `/home/git/gitlab` directory:

```
wget http://rubygems.org/downloads/modernizr-2.6.2.gem
```

Then, go ahead and run `gem install modernizr` (without changing directories) and the utility will search in the local directory for the gem file before trying to fetch it remotely. This is the gem we're looking for.

NOTE: It looks like some people are still having problems with this solution, so something else we can do is replace a few lines in `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` (both on `/home/git/gitlab`), switching `modernizr` for `modernizr-rails`:

- in `Gemfile`, line 164, change `"modernizr", "2.6.2"` to `"modernizr-rails", "2.7.1"`
- in `Gemfile.lock`, line 292, change `modernizr (2.6.2)` to `modernizr-rails (2.7.1)`
- in `Gemfile.lock`, line 626, change `modernizr (= 2.6.2)` to `modernizr-rails (= 2.7.1)`

This second solution is thanks to [csj4032](https://github.com/csj4032) on Github.

Comment: We're actually looking for `modernizer-2.6.2.gem`, but other then that this works :)

Comment: Kudos! After the second part, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Does anybody know why the modernizr gems were yanked?

Comment: the second solution followed by:
`sudo bundle install --no-deployment`
was the sollution for me. Thank you.

Comment: When editing, use run as git user the commands: `sudo -u git -H nano Gemfile` and `sudo -u git -H nano Gemfile.lock`

Comment: I get access forbidden when use the solution. Have other way ?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone arrives at this page like me, use the latest version of the doc at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md -- as this is fixed in 6.7. For some reason I was following steps with 6.6.

Answer (score 1):

this makes success on Centos 6.4, Ruby 2.2.1, git 1.9.3, gitlab 6-6-stable.

> "In Gemfile, line 164, change "modernizr", "2.6.2" to "modernizr-rails", "2.7.1". In Gemfile.lock, line 292, change modernizr (2.6.2) to modernizr-rails (2.7.1) and on line 626, change modernizr (= 2.6.2) to modernizr-rails (= 2.7.1)."

thanks to L0j1k, and csj4032 on Github.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

I modified Gemfile inside your /home/git/gitlab and put this

gem "modernizr", "2.6.2", :git => 'https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git', :branch => 'master', :tag => 'v2.7.2'